# Multiple user sessions data interfering with each other

Tags: angular, spring, session, digital-ocean

We have built an application using Angular for frontend and SpringBoot for Backend, hosted using DigitalOcean Droplet. We are facing issues with multiple user sessions.

The data for each user is interfering with each other. Is there anyway to have multiple sessions to avoid this issue?

Comment: can you please share your current implementation how you are manaing the session

Comment: A session is meant to be attached to a user. Each user connecting to your app will have its own session, that's the goal of this mechanism. If multiple sessions interfere, you must be using them wrong, so please share your code using/writing to session so we may see what you are doing wrong